# Probability as input to Markov random field (MRF): how to refine the cmex code?

Tags: c++, computer-vision, caffe, image-segmentation, markov-random-fields

I am very new with `MRF` and not that much good at programming. 
I have obtained probability map from semantic segmentation using a CNN, I have to optimize the segmentation by using Markov Random Fields (MRF). 
I download the code provided by Shai Bagon in this link [GCmex](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex). Energy minimization is performed based on either alpha expansion or swap.

I compiled the code by mex and I need to refine the Unary and pair-wise energy minimization functions. I have a stack of images and need to extract the 6-neighborhood grid and include the refined neighboring in the pair-wise function.

The input to the Unary function is the probability map which is a stack with size (256,256,4) for 4 different classes:
[image]

My questions are: 
Has someone refined the code according to the defining different energy function 1) I wanna change Unary and pair-wise formulation). Which functions and which parts of code should be refined and recompiled again?

2) How to change the `w_i,j`? it is calculate based on intensity difference, here we have only probabilities, Is it the difference of probabilities of two adjacent voxels?

I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: How many 256x256x4 probability maps do you have? It seems like you have a map for each 2D slice, but you are doing 3D segmentation? how many slices do you have? Do you have the source images/slices for which you got the probability maps?

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for responding, I am doing 2d segmentation by Cnn, which the output is 4 probability maps for one image (each probability map relates to one class), however, I have to do optimization by MRF using a grid of 6-neighbors (4 in current probability map and the other 2 in adjacent probability map of same class from the sequence.  For the time being I want to do for each class separately (binary) to see how it works and the extend for all classes. How can I do it? which functions need to be changed for new data and smoothing terms?Thanks a lot.

Comment: 6-connect is for 3D grids. Your grid is 2D, you can have either 4-connect or 8-connect. The graph only connects neighboring pixels and not neighboring entries in probability map.

Comment: It is a 6-neighbors in a grid of probability of a certain class (for example i). For example,If the current voxel is (r,c,k), the neighborhood includes 4 neighbors of the voxel plus two other neighbors from adjacent slices (probability of class i in slice k-1 and k+1, which are two voxel in (r,c,k+1) and (r,c,k-1). Since your GCmex code accepts an rgb image with discrete values, how can I refine it to take continuous probabilities [0,1] and which functions should change for refining potential terms? Thanks for your help

Comment: so you have 4D probability map: `(r,c,k)x4`. do you have the input slices? what exactly do you have?

Comment: Yes, I have 60 images in a sequence and their ground truth (with 4 labels 0-3), each time I am sending a single image to CNN and output gives a stack of 4 probability maps per each class. Now I have to maximize the posterior prob. by using MRF (alpha-exp. or alpha-betha). All together,   image, gt and stack of 4 as probability maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 60 slices of `256x256` pix (tot ~4G voxels), that is `slices` is a `256`-by-`256`-by-`60` array. Once you feed `slices` into your net (one by one or in batches - whatever works best for you) you have `prob` probability of size `256`-by-`256`-by-`60`-by-`4`.
I suggest you use [third constructor of `GCMex`](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex/blob/master/GraphCut.m#L20) to construct your graph for optimization.
To do so, you first need to define a sparse graph. Use [`sparse_adj_matrix`](https://github.com/shaibagon/GCMex/blob/master/sparse_adj_matrix.m):

```matlab
[ii jj] = sparse_adj_matrix([256 256 60], 1, 1);  % 6-connect 3D grid
n = prod([256 256 60]);  % num voxels
wij = exp(-((slices(ii)-slices(jj)).^2)/(2*sig2));  % -|Ii-Ij|^2/2\sig^2
W = sparse(ii, jj, wij, n, n);  % sparse grid graph
```

Once you have the graph, it's all down hill from here:

```matlab
Dc = -reallog(reshape(prob, n, 4)).';  %' unary/data term 
lambda = 2;  % relative weight of the smoothness term
gch = GraphCut('open', Dc, lambda*(ones(4)-eye(4)), W);  % construct the graph
[gch L] = GraphCut('expand', gch);  % minimize using "expand" method
gch = GraphCut('close', gch);  % do not forget to de-allocate
```

To see the output labels, you need to `reshape`

```matlab
output = reshape(L, size(slices));
```

PS,
If your spatial distance between slices is larger than the gap between neighboring voxels in the same slice, you might need to use different `sig2` for `ii` and `jj` that are in the same slice and for `ii` and `jj` that are on different slices.  This requires a bit of an effort.

Comment: Thanks, I loaded 4 maps into `prob` by for loop , `prob(:,:,i,:)= cat(4, squeeze(pMap.a(1,:,:)), squeeze(pMap.a(2,:,:)), squeeze(pMap.a(3,:,:)),
        squeeze(pMap.a(4,:,:)))`, however, I am getting error: `Error using GraphCut>OpenGraph (line 383)
Wrong size of Dc or Sc`. The size of Dc is 3932160-by-4 after reshaping. I do not know why?!

Comment: it's been a while since I last used this package. it might be the case that you need to transpose Dc

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, Dc was changed to Dc' however, does not improve the segmentation results that much. I set `sig=0.01`;

Comment: you might want to increase the relative weight of the smoothness term. You can do that by multiplying `W` by `\lambda > 1` factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I did that one too, however, not that much improvement. Edges became a little bit more smoother. CNN was under-segmenting and I was thinking to improve it by increasing the posterior probability of probability maps by using MRF.

Comment: you might need to increase `\lambda` significantly. Try very large value until you see only large smooth blobs in the output, and then decrease to get the proper amount of smoothing you wish to get.

Comment: Dear Shai, In the demo [http://vision.ucla.edu/~brian/gcmex.html] that Brian Fulkerson provides, the function is taking `CLASS` labels as well `[LABELS ENERGY ENERGYAFTER] = GCMEX(CLASS, UNARY, PAIRWISE, LABELCOST,EXPANSION)` . How it works with your version? Thanks

Comment: Could I ask if it is `[gch] = GraphCut('set', gch, labels)`, which `labels` is vectorized ground truth matrix? What is the advantages of giving the labels to GC? Thanks

Comment: @S.EB a good initialization can sometimes help in getting a better solution

Comment: Thanks for your help. May I ask another question, is there any formula to find out `lambda`  value? or we should continuously try different values? what do you suggest? Thanks

Comment: @S.EB it's an open question. You may find the paper on parametric maxflow by C. Rother et al. relevant